# Axios: Network Error and not sending request

Tags: vuejs2, httprequest, axios

I am trying to send a get request with auth headers to api from Vue using axios.

When I try to send it, it gives me a `Network Error` with no info about it. I have also check network tab and the request is not sending at all.

Before I checked the url using postman and https://www.hurl.it/ and it worked as expected.

Also, I have sent a request to this api using axios to get a token.

Thank you.

```js
const token = "token";

let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://smev.test-it-studio.ru/api/analytics/PortfolioStructure',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
};

axios(options).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

**EDIT:** Here is the error I get:

```
Error
  columnNumber: 15
  config: {…}
    adapter: function xhrAdapter()
    baseURL: "http://smev.test-it-studio.ru"
    data: undefined
    headers: Object { Accept: "application/json", Authorization: "Bearer token"}
    maxContentLength: -1
    method: "GET"
    timeout: 0
    transformRequest: Object [ transformRequest() ]
    transformResponse: Object [ transformResponse() ]
    url: "http://smev.test-it-studio.ru/api/analytics/PortfolioStructure"
    validateStatus: function validateStatus()
    xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
    xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
    __proto__: Object { … }
  fileName: "http://uralsib-lk.dev/dist/build.js"
  lineNumber: 19074
  message: "Network Error"
  response: undefined
  stack: "createError@http://uralsib-lk.dev/dist/build.js:19074:15\nhandleError@http://uralsib-lk.dev/dist/build.js:18962:14\n"
  __proto__: Object { … }
  build.js:18589:24
```

Comment: Could you log the complete error object and not only error.config?

Comment: Could this be because of CORS? I read other questions, they get different error when it is CORS

Comment: Hmm, not sure as you wrote you tested with hurl.It and it worked. Is it correct that the protocol is http ?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this request using fetch(), got the same error. `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource`. The request is not even sent, as it's not showing in the network tab

Comment: By the way, API is written in ASP.NET if it helps

Comment: Tested it myself with the exact code you posted and I get an expected 403 error as I don't have the right token.
But in addition I get: XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Not sure where this is coming from. Is your API expecting XML? Axios does json.

Comment: Strange, when I try sending it without any headers, I still get a network error. If you can, could you try it with the token please, I included it in the post. I don't know much about this API, as I am not writing it

Comment: yes, it works. status 200 and the response contains an array with 4 objects and each with 4 fields. Perhaps you have a problem with your host which doesn't allow outgoing taffic?

Comment: Thanks for testing. How can I check that?

Comment: You're welcome! :) Could you describe your dev environment? And are you perhaps behind a firewall or so?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS High Sierra and just using a webpack server. I have checked the firewall and it's off

Comment: Ok, so I found out that I only have this problem on Firefox, just tried Chrome and everything works as expected

Comment: Ok, cool. But also interesting. Which Firefox are you using? I used Firefox too.

Comment: Firefox Quantum v57.0.4

Comment: Tested with the same version now and it works. Perhaps cache or so?

Comment: I found out why it didn't work. It was the adblocker, after I disabled it, was able to send the request normally. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: !!! :D You're welcome! That is good to know! Perhaps you would like to post an answer to it yourself? I guess others are going to have the same problem. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help from [Soleno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738720/soleno), I found out that it was AdBlock what was blocking the request.

Comment: I have been tearing my hair out with a similar issue. I was only having issues with the "Network Error" popping up when I was testing running a front-end from my local machine.

I saw your reply and then noticed that privacy badger was blocking access to the back-end. Days of frustration fixed in seconds.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from spending hours in vain. I had an endpoint (/api/v1/ad/..) that AdBlock blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in rails.  It was cors as mentioned above.
The rails server won't show logs so it looks like axios isn't sending the request at all.

Thankfully it's an easy fix.

For rails add this to your gemfile:
`gem 'rack-cors'`

Then add this to config/initializers/cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0,Rack::Cors do  

allow do
  origins 'localhost:8080'

  resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

**Note**: Update orgins to the origin of your front end app.